# Excel VBA - Running excel macros on specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I am edditing an Excel macro which can creat barcodes.

**My Problem:** The code is quite heavy and Excel calcualtes permanently in each sheet after typing. I was trying to copying the code to a sheet instead modul but could not figure it to make the code running only for a specific sheet. Attached is the example file.

**Solution:** Restrict the code for a specific sheet to prevent excel calculating permanently

**Here is a code snippets:**

```
Dim IsMs As Boolean
Sub Init()
  If VarType(Asc("A")) = 2 Then IsMs = True Else IsMs = False
End Sub

Public Function EncodeBarcode(ShIx As Integer, xAddr As String, _
            code As String, pbctype%, Optional pgraficky%, _
            Optional pparams%, Optional pzones%) As String
  Dim s$, bctype%, graficky%, params%, zones%
  Dim oo As Object

  Call Init
  If IsMissing(pzones) Then zones = 2 Else zones = pzones
  If IsMissing(pparams) Then params = 0 Else params = pparams
  If IsMissing(pgraficky) Then graficky = 1 Else graficky = pgraficky
  If IsMissing(pbctype) Then bctype = 0 Else bctype = pbctype
  Select Case bctype



    Case 51 ' QRCode params: ECLevel 0=M 1=L 2=Q 3=H
      s = "mode=" & Mid("MLQH", (params Mod 4) + 1, 1)
      s = qr_gen(code, s)

  End Select
  If graficky <> 0 Then
    If bctype >= 50 Then
      If IsMs Then
        Call bc_2Dms(s)
      Else
        Call bc_2D(ShIx, xAddr, s)
      End If
Else
  If IsMs Then

  Else

  End If
End If
EncodeBarcode = ""
  Else
    EncodeBarcode = s
  End If
  Exit Function
End Function

Function AscL(s As String) As Long
  If IsMs Then AscL = AscW(s) Else AscL = Asc(s)
End Function
```

Comment: You created your own function, so on whichever sheet you enter the function in a cell it will recalculate. If you want to reduce the amount of recalculations, you should set calculation mode to manual. Or move your code to a seperate workbook.

Comment: So this means I can not limit the function to only one sheet to prevent recalculations in other sheets?

Comment: Well the way excel works is that it builds a dependence tree, and if something in that dependence tree changes, the entire tree gets recalculated. Now you have two options as I said. Either disable calculation of the entire workbook, and only recalculate the workbook manually. Or split all other sheets from the sheet that contains your function, and only pass the minimal required data to the workbook with your function.

Comment: @Luuklag Ok I will try it, many thanks.